# Parse OpenClipArt api json to Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to Parse this json http://openclipart.org/search/json/?&query=christmas&page=1&amount=4 in my html page.

My code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
        <style>
            img {
                height: 200px;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="images"></div>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var api = "http://openclipart.org/search/json/?";
                $.getJSON( api, {
                    query: "christmas",
                    page: "1",
                    amount: "4"
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    $.each( data.payload, function( i, item ) {
                        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.svg.png_thumb ).appendTo( "#images");
                        if ( i === 3 ) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n8ax/, But something is wrong.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: They have fixed it :DDD Thank you openclipart <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not working on jsFiddle is because of Same-origin policy.

What this means is, you are *not* allowed to access resources on another domain (http://openclipart.org/) from jsfiddle.net.

See these two resources:

1. [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
2. [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)